# How to redirect an url htacces mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an url to redirect with `htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`.

- Original url: `htpp://www.example.com/tag/citta/?lang=en/feed/`
- New url: `http://www.example.com/en/offers-events/`

I try with this code but don't work

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/tag/citta/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=en$
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/feed/$
RewriteRule   .*   /en/offers-events/? [R=301,L]
```

How can I redirect the url?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en/feed/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^tag/citta/?$ /en/offers-events/? [NC,R=301,L]
```